# Word for naming (complex, abstract) phenomena

Tags: terminology

Is there a word or a (catch) phrase for naming more or less complex, mostly abstract phenomena?

An example for this is the naming of the phenomenon known as serendipity as "serendipity".

Naming the fruit we call apple an "apple" for the first time would of course be an example for coining a term, but it lacks something that is related to the naming of "complex" abstract phenomena: i.e. after it has a label, it "comes into existence" because it can be much better perceived, used in context, etc.

Reification (at least how computer scientists use the term) seems to be related, but it is not completely fitting.

Comment: This might be better asked on the English stack exchange site: https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for the remark. I will ask that question there, but the word I am looking for seems to be a very specific one, similar to reification, a term used in philosophy.

Comment: Peirce called it [hypostatic abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypostatic_abstraction).

Comment: 'In the beginning was the Word', and with it reification. Why is 'apple' not an example of the naming of a complex phenomenon? I cannot quite nail down what the question is asking. Perhaps Conifold has already answered it.